# Mysql and PHP leaderboard acting strange

Tags: php, mysql, leaderboard

I am trying to make a leaderboard and sort my data by kills, but when I try to make it so it only grabs name, kill, death it doesnt grab anything but when I have it grab it all it works. Anyone know why? Code is below please assist.

```
<?php
                    $query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT * from `player`");
                    $query->execute();
                    if($query->rowCount() == 0)
```

I am grabbing my mysql data here, if I change the * to the data I need no data is displayed.

```
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>There's no player on ban list</small></td></tr>";
                    }
                    while($data = $query->fetch())
                    {
                        echo "<tr><td>".$data['name']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$data['kill']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$data['death']."</td>";
                        $kd = $data['kill'] / $data['death'];
                        echo "<td>".$kd."</td></tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Is it something to do with this or is something wrong? I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use `bind_result()` and in that you have to pass the number of parameters which is equal to your number of field from your `player` table.
Because here you are fetching data using `select *` query.